# how to install imutils 0.2 for python in windows 07

Tags: python, windows, installation

I want to install imutils 0.2 package to python and i have windows 7 operating system. I only found the gz file and would like to know the way of gz files. Or else if there are any exe files available please let me know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install pip: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Then you can install packages like:

`pip install imutils`

Alternatively, you could unpack the gz (something like Winzip should be able to handle it) and run `python setup.py install`.

Comment: I needed to install imutils with my Python 3 installation, and pip only installed it for Python 2. However, running `python3 setup.py install` got it working on Python 3. Thanks!

Comment: @VinceFior you can have `pip` alongside with `pip3`, see this thread for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/pip-dealing-with-multiple-python-versions

Answer (score 1):

In windows, py3, `conda install imutils` is not avaliable.

`pip3 install imutils` 
and the newest version will be installed.

Answer (score 0):

Using windows 7, Anaconda3 environment I tried: pip install imutils 
which gave me a "got an unexpected keyword argument 'keyword encoding' error...so after much "wringing of hands and gnashing of teeth.." I arrived at the following solution:

go to: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/imutils and download: imutils-0.4.5.tar.gzip

extract the imutils-0.4.5 to folder of your choosing.

run: python setup.py install

Sadly, stupid, but it worked for me!!